# Will my Gai Lan come back on its own?

Tags: planting, brassicas

I planted a dozen [gai lan plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gai_lan) in a container last year. They did very well and I got a nice harvest of leaves, and then let them go to seed.

It's been a very warm winter here in Portland, OR, and as a result they haven't died off; the plants are still alive in their container.  Can I just trim them, and expect them to re-leaf in the spring, or do I need to pull them up and replant from seed?